# Fix how to display realtime location of the user in google map using onion.maugoogle.maps nuget

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I tried this code

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

but i cant show it on display